# Create a linked list for all nodes attahced by node with cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I´m struggling to do a linked list with a cypher statement. I´m trying to do the following for each k. The linked list and :NEXT relationship should be isolated by k.

```
match (elem:Event)<-[r:HAS_EVENT]-(k)
WITH elem ORDER BY elem.id ASC
WITH COLLECT(elem) AS elems
FOREACH (n IN RANGE(0, LENGTH(elems)-2) |
FOREACH (prec IN [elems[n]] |
FOREACH (next IN [elems[n+1]] |
MERGE (prec)-[:NEXT]->(next))))
```

Since it´s not possible to do a MATCH statement inside a FOREACH statement I tried MATCH (a:Some_Label) with a as x UNWIND x as k  and other possible ways to run this code by for each k (id lockup etc). I always end up with a long chain of :NEXT throu all :Event nodes, suggesting that the match statement considers all k nodes. I need help on how to match :Some_Label nodes and pass each one of them to the above code.

Comment: How does your data look like and who is `k`? Can you describe your problem simpler/more detailed?

Comment: k is a support ticket in this case. So i want to create a linked list for each ticket. Each :Event nod has some other nodes attached to it, status, categorization etc. Each :Ticket node has several :Event nodes attached to it. :Ticket and :Event labels are indexed by id 

The problem is that i would like to take the tickets (MATCH (k:Ticket) that I have in my graph and run the above code for each k from a previous match statement. Ideally from a LOAD CSV statement since new entries would be loaded that way, but that is not neccessary.

Comment: MATCH (a:Ticket) with a
  ---SOMETHING---
   match (elem:Event)<-[r:HAS_EVENT]-(k)
   WITH elem ORDER BY elem.id ASC
   WITH COLLECT(elem) AS elems
   FOREACH (n IN RANGE(0, LENGTH(elems)-2) |
   FOREACH (prec IN [elems[n]] |
   FOREACH (next IN [elems[n+1]] |
   MERGE (prec)-[:NEXT]->(next))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like there are two parts to this. First, matching on just the k nodes that you want included in a linked list (filtering, sorting, and so forth).

Once you have this, all you need to do is COLLECT them into a list, and use `apoc.coll.pairs([list]) YIELD value` . This changes the list into a list of pairs of each sequential element ([[first, second], [second, third]...]). You just have to watch out for the last pair, which is [last, null].

At that point all you need to do is do a FOREACH on each element (pair) and merge your :NEXT relationship.

EDIT

Looks like you're using the periodic function to iterate over the k elements you're interested in. You can use the COLLECT() and pairs() function to replace your nested FOREACH loops.

UPDATE

While there is an `apoc.coll.pairsMin()` function that ensures we don't have a null within the last pairing, it's highly recommended nowadays to use `apoc.nodes.link()` instead, passing the ordered list of nodes to link together and the type of the relationship to use:

```
Match (elem:Event)<-[r:HAS_EVENT]-(k)
WITH elem ORDER BY elem.id ASC
WITH COLLECT(elem) AS elems
CALL apoc.nodes.link(elems, 'NEXT')
RETURN elems
```

Comment: Following up, it looks like there are issues with using pairs generated by the pairs() procedure within FOREACH. [This bug](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/issues/94) captures the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to create the `NEXT` chain within a list of `Events`. And each `Event` list comes from a `MATCH` to a specific `k` node.

I think you might be able to achieve this with just a slightly different `WITH` clause followed by the ordering step:

```
MATCH (k:Ticket) // however you match here...
WITH k
// MATCH your k to Events
MATCH (elem:Event)<-[r:HAS_EVENT]-(k)
// include k in the WITH clause
// now you have one result 'row' per k with the matching elem nodes
WITH k, COLLECT(elem) AS elems
// UNWIND, ORDER BY and collect() again to sort the list in each row
UNWIND elems AS x
WITH x ORDER BY x.id ASC
WITH collect(x) AS ordered_elems_per_k
// now the foreach should be applied for each k/list of elem pair
FOREACH (n IN RANGE(0, LENGTH(ordered_elems_per_k)-2) |
FOREACH (prec IN [ordered_elems_per_k[n]] |
FOREACH (next IN [ordered_elems_per_k[n+1]] |
MERGE (prec)-[:NEXT]->(next))))
```

I think it's not possible to combine `ORDER BY` and `collect()`. This would solve your problem in a simpler way, but something along this line should work.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this via;

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate('Match (a:Ticket) return id(a) as id_p', 
'match (elem:Event)<-[r:HAS_EVENT]-(k) where id(k)={id_p} 
WITH elem ORDER BY elem.id ASC WITH COLLECT(elem) AS elems 
FOREACH (n IN RANGE(0, LENGTH(elems)-2) | 
FOREACH (prec IN [elems[n]] | 
FOREACH (next IN [elems[n+1]] | MERGE (prec)-[:NEXT]->(next))))',
{batchSize:1000,parallel:true}) YIELD batches, total
```